# Request failed: unauthorized (401) with Twitter login

Tags: ios, swift, twitter

I am trying to login with Twitter in my iOS app but I am getting following error:

```
CredStore - performQuery - Error copying matching creds.  Error=-25300, query={
class = inet;
"m_Limit" = "m_LimitAll";
ptcl = htps;
"r_Attributes" = 1;
sdmn = "https://api.twitter.com";
srvr = "api.twitter.com";
sync = syna;
}
error: Optional("Request failed: unauthorized (401)")
```

My code for login:

```
Twitter.sharedInstance().logIn(completion: { (session, error) in
        if (session != nil) {
            print("signed in as \(session?.userName)");

            let client = TWTRAPIClient(userID: session?.userName)
            client.loadUser(withID: (session?.userID)!, completion: { (user, error) in

                let twitterClient = TWTRAPIClient.withCurrentUser()
                let request = twitterClient.urlRequest(withMethod: "GET",
                                                       url: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/list.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=dearestpankaj&skip_status=true&include_user_entities=false",
                                                       parameters: ["include_email": "true", "skip_status": "true"],
                                                       error: nil)

                twitterClient.sendTwitterRequest(request) { response, data, connectionError in
                    print(data!)
                    let s :String = String(data: data! as Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!

                    if let data = s.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
                        do {
                            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String:Any]
                            print(json!)

                        } catch {
                            print("Something went wrong")
                        }
                    }
                }
            })

        } else {
            print("error: \(error?.localizedDescription)");
        }
    })
```

Yesterday this error was intermittent but today I am continuously getting this error.

Comment: At first glance, it doesn't appear that you're doing anything to actually authenticate the request.  Am I correct or am I missing something?  All calls to the Twitter REST API have to be authenticated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change this value: `let client = TWTRAPIClient(userID: session?.userName)`

with this : `let client = TWTRAPIClient(userID: session?.userID)`

Comment: Debugger never reaches till this point, session is nil so it leaves it earlier

Answer (score 1):

I was using “pod ‘TwitterKit’” I changed the line in the podfile to “pod ‘TwitterKit’, ‘~> 3.0’” and everything seems to be working correctly now.

Answer (score 0):

You should go to your Application Settings on Twitter page and setup:
**Callback URL**
and
**Callback URL Locked** set to **YES**

After that everything should work